# control digital signing

Tags: digital-signature

What is the secure way to support dev mode and production modes on embedded systems that support digital signing. Dev mode will skip signature verification.

Answer (score 1):

The same way that Windows 10 does:

[image]

Add a setting to it that lets its owner/administrator enable "Developer Mode". This is secure as it gets unless your security model is something evil like "keep the device safe from its owner so I can do DRM".